# Can't loop more than 1 row Mysql

Tags: php, database, mysqli, while-loop

I'm trying to get all rows from database , but when my database only have 1 row, it will show on website, if i'm add more 1 row, nothing show in website.

My code:

```
require_once('data/class.dbsetting.php');

Mysql sql = new Mysql();

sql->connect();

$query = 'select * from accounts';
$result = $sql->query($query);

While($row = $sql->fetch_assoc($result))
{
  echo $row['Username'];
}
```

Comment: Please add `var_dump($result);` and show us the result

Comment: It's weird that you're using a `new mysql()` and using it. I don't know if you have hidden it in your code for the question or if you're not using any connection data.

Comment: Sorry , my class is mySql, it will be mySql sql = new mySql();

Comment: Here var_dump($result), object(mysqli_result)#3 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(11) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(0) }

Answer (score 0):

Try with :

```
mysql_fetch_all($result,MYSQL_ASSOC);
```